# How to pass global JS var within regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

This is my regexp

```
regexp:{
spamcheck    : /^[15]+$/
}
```

I need to do this

```
var spamcheck_sum = 15;

regexp:{
spamcheck    : /^[spamcheck_sum]+$/
}
```

and

Side note: I cant use my spamcheck_sum var outside the js  reason is my js file loads first and  my var for sum loads after , any way to globalize that var to be acceptable no matter if js file loads first?

working with cms here and js file placement is automatic if I use the cms js placements calls . Joomla

Comment: Ive been wondering this myself

Comment: Are you sure that is the regex you want? It will match the string `"151555151515151515"`.

Comment: @Quentin: Or `11111111` or `5555555` or `15155151551515151151515515515151`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var spamcheck_sum = 15;

regexp:{
spamcheck    : new RegExp("^["+spamcheck_sum+"]+$")
}
```

Comment: that is the one but just saw that I cant use it outside the file . reason is my js file loads first and  my var for sum loads after , any way to globalize that var to be acceptable no matter if js file loads first?

Comment: How about a method that accepts check_sum as an input parameter and handles the rest?

Comment: trust me I would not know how , this is a formcheck from mootools floor that I am modifying to put in Joomla module  http://mootools.floor.ch/docs/formcheck/files/formcheck-js.html

Comment: but none the less I fund a way instead calling the js file with $document->addScript('')  I used  $document->addCustomTag('<style type="text/css"></style>')  this way I can place it anywhere , but it would be nice to know how to do this global var to be acceptable no matter of file position

Comment: @Benn: Not everything is possible. You can only use a value once it is set.

Comment: I believe you have no control over page the loading! Normally scripts run as soon as they are loaded, using the defer attribute might help, it specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing: <script defer="defer">

Comment: good thinking! <script defer="defer">